# How to read which checkboxes have been selected (HTML form to Google Sheet)

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Praveen Kumar's  script to send HTML form data to a Google Sheet (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39XZBKmcMfE&ab_channel=CodingMSTR).

It works great, but the only example code was for simple text inputs. How might this work for a checkbox input?

The form:

[image]

Currently if any of the checkboxes are selected, the value "on" is passed, otherwise blank but I need to see in the Google Sheet which of the checkboxes have been selected:

[image]

The HTML form:

```
<form method="post" name="google-sheet" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="mb-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="form-FName" name="FName" placeholder="Your First Name"></div>
    <div class="mb-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="form-LName" name="LName" placeholder="Your Surname (optional)"></div>
    <div class="mb-3"><input class="form-control" type="email" id="form-Email" name="Email" placeholder="Your email address"></div>
    <div class="mb-3"><input class="form-control" type="tel" id="form-Phone" name="Phone" placeholder="Your phone number (preferably mobile)"></div>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>How can I contact you?</legend>
            <div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-1" name="HowContact"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Text</label></div>
            <div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-3" name="HowContact"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-3">Phone - daytime</label></div>
            <div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-2" name="HowContact"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">Phone - early evening</label></div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div><button class="btn btn-primary d-block w-100" type="submit" name="submit" style="margin-top: 18px;">Send </button></div>
    <div></div>
</form>
```

The Javascript in the HTML page:

```
<script>
const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyDwOEAmWRazqBBpSEoPxp0gj3vZQxXVwRf7BGnvep5wRD2_xdI9efKjeIXPU4XTzftnQ/exec'
const form = document.forms['google-sheet']

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
    .then(response => alert("Thanks for Contacting us..! We Will Contact You Soon..."))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
})
</script>
```

The Appscript doGet function:

```
  function doPost(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function (header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

UPDATE: After Tanaike's suggestion, the sheet receives a value but when selecting more than one item, only the first one is sent to the sheet:
[image: ![enter image description here]
[image]

The updated form:

```
<fieldset>
     <legend>How can I contact you?</legend>
     <div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-1" name="HowContact" value="text"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Text</label></div>
     <div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-3" name="HowContact" value="ph-day"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-3">Phone - daytime</label></div>
     <div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-2" name="HowContact" value="ph-eve"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">Phone - early evening</label></div>
 </fieldset>
```

The updated Appscript:

```
try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function (header) {
    return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameters[header].join(",");
    });

    // var newRow = headers.map(function (header) {
    //   return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    // })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your HTML, it seems that `value` is not set in the input tag. So, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### HTML side:

Please modify your HTML as follows.

##### From:

```
<div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-1" name="HowContact"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Text</label></div>
<div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-3" name="HowContact"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-3">Phone - daytime</label></div>
<div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-2" name="HowContact"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">Phone - early evening</label></div>
```

##### To:

```
<div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-1" name="HowContact" value="Text"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Text</label></div>
<div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-3" name="HowContact" value="Phone - daytime"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-3">Phone - daytime</label></div>
<div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-2" name="HowContact" value="Phone - early evening"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">Phone - early evening</label></div>
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

In order to use the multiple responses, please modify Google Apps Script as follows.

##### From:

```
var newRow = headers.map(function (header) {
   return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
 })
```

##### To:

```
var newRow = headers.map(function (header) {
  return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameters[header].join(",");
});
```

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

### Added:

If your HTML and Javascript are put in the same Google Apps Script project of `doPost`, I thought that the following modification might be able to be used.

#### HTML & Javascript: `index.html`

```html
<form method="post" name="google-sheet" autocomplete="off" id="form">
    <div class="mb-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="form-FName" name="FName" placeholder="Your First Name"></div>
    <div class="mb-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="form-LName" name="LName" placeholder="Your Surname (optional)"></div>
    <div class="mb-3"><input class="form-control" type="email" id="form-Email" name="Email" placeholder="Your email address"></div>
    <div class="mb-3"><input class="form-control" type="tel" id="form-Phone" name="Phone" placeholder="Your phone number (preferably mobile)"></div>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>How can I contact you?</legend>
<div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-1" name="HowContact" value="Text"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Text</label></div>
<div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-3" name="HowContact" value="Phone - daytime"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-3">Phone - daytime</label></div>
<div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-2" name="HowContact" value="Phone - early evening"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-2">Phone - early evening</label></div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div><button class="btn btn-primary d-block w-100" type="submit" name="submit" style="margin-top: 18px;">Send </button></div>
    <div></div>
</form>

<script>
const form = document.forms['google-sheet'];
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(res => {
    console.log(res);
    alert("Thanks for Contacting us..! We Will Contact You Soon...");
  }).saveData(form);
})
</script>
```

#### Google Apps Script: `Code.gs`

```js
// If you are using a dialog and sidebar, please use it. If you are using Web Apps, you can use this.
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index"); // Please set the html filename.
}

function saveData(e) {
  var sheetName = "###"; // Please set sheet name.
  var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(10000);
  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
    var newRow = headers.map(function (header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : Array.isArray(e[header]) ? e[header].join(",") : e[header];
    })
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
    return { 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow };
  } catch (e) {
    return { 'result': 'error', 'error': e };
  } finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

- In this modification, even when the Web Apps is deployed as a new version and the URL of Web Apps is changed, this script works because the Web Apps URL is not used for `fetch` API.
- When you use this script, please copy and paste the above scripts to a Google Apps Script project, and please deploy Web Apps. When you access the created Web Apps URL, the HTML is opened. And, when you submit the HTML form, the values are put on the Spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your response. Partially working; please see my update.

Comment: @MrGreggles Thank you for replying. From your added information. In this case, I'm worried that you might have still not modified the Google Apps Script side for using the multiple responses. Please confirm it again. And, when you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.

Comment: The appscript was updated (included now in the update details). I deployed as new and had to change the url, which I assume is okay. I wasn't quite sure how to do the new version without changing the url.

Comment: @MrGreggles Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I think that even when the URL is changed when the latest script is refected in the Web Apps, the script works. About `I wasn't quite sure how to do the new version without changing the url.`, I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @MrGreggles As an important point, when the Web Apps is deployed as a new version and the URL was changed, in your script, please also modify the Web Apps URL of `scriptURL`. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Oh yes I did that. The form still works - it's just that it only shows the first selected value in the sheet.

Comment: @MrGreggles Thank you for replying. About `Oh yes I did that. The form still works - it's just that it only shows the first selected value. `, when I tested my proposed modification, the multiple responses can be put to the sheet. So, in this case, it is considered that your latest script is still not correctly reflected in the Web Apps.

Comment: @MrGreggles In your situation, where is the Google Apps Script? It's outside of Google drive? If it's so, when you change the Web Apps URL, the script works.

Comment: @MrGreggles If it's included in the same Google Apps Script project with `doPost(e)` and you want to use your showing script, it is required to reflect the current script in the Google Apps Script project without changing the Web Apps URL. Because when the Web Apps URL is changed, the script is required to be reflected in the Web Apps. In this case, please confirm this again. https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43 When the my modified script is correctly reflected in your script, the script works.

Comment: @MrGreggles As another modification pattern, if your HTML and Javascript are put in the same Google Apps Script project of `doPost`, how about the added script? In that added script, even when the Web Apps is deployed as a new version and the URL of Web Apps is changed, this script works because the Web Apps URL is not used for `fetch` API.

Comment: It's now working! I think my mistake was simply not refreshing the form page [blush]. BTW the appscript is attached to the sheet (via the standard 'Extensions | Appscript' menu option. I'll check your new info too. Thank you!!

Comment: @MrGreggles Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About my added script, when your HTML&Javascript are not included in the same Google Apps Script project of `doPost`, this script cannot be used. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248007/discussion-between-mrgreggles-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that create checkboxes on the fly and also a couple static ones and then reads them. It's actually a complete solution for backing up your script functions into ascii files.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
        input {margin: 2px 5px 2px 0;}
    #btn3,#btn4{display:none}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="scr" name="script" size="60" placeholder="Enter Apps Script Id" onchange="getFileNames();" />
        <br /><input type="text" id="fldr" name="folder" size="60" placeholder="Enter Backup Folder Id" />
        <div id="shts"></div>
    <br /><input type="button" value="0" onClick="unCheckAll();" size="15" id="btn3" />
    <input type="button" value="1" onClick="checkAll();"size="15" id="btn4"/>
        <br /><input type="checkbox" id="files" name="saveFiles" checked /><label for="files">Save Files</label>
        <br /><input type="checkbox" id="json" name="saveJson" checked /><label for="json">Save JSON</label>
        <br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="backupFiles();" />
    </form>
        <script>
      function getFileNames() {
        const scriptid = document.getElementById("scr").value;
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler((names) => {
          document.getElementById('btn3').style.display = "inline";
          document.getElementById('btn4').style.display = "inline";
          names.forEach((name,i) => {
           let br = document.createElement("br"); 
           let cb = document.createElement("input");
           cb.type = "checkbox";
           cb.id = `cb${i}`;
           cb.name = `cb${i}`;
           cb.className = "cbx";
           cb.value = `${name}`;
           cb.checked = true;
           let lbl = document.createElement("label");
           lbl.htmlFor = `cb${i}`;
           lbl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${name}`));
           document.getElementById("shts").appendChild(cb);
           document.getElementById("shts").appendChild(lbl);
           document.getElementById("shts").appendChild(br);
          });
        })
        .getAllFileNames({scriptId:scriptid}); 
      }
      function unCheckAll() {
        let btns = document.getElementsByClassName("cbx");
        console.log(btns.length);
        for(let i =0;i<btns.length;i++) {
          btns[i].checked = false;
        }
      }
      function checkAll() {
        let btns = document.getElementsByClassName("cbx");
        console.log(btns.length)
        for(let i = 0;i<btns.length;i++) {
          btns[i].checked = true; 
        }
      }
      function backupFiles() {
        console.log('backupFiles');
        sObj = {};
        sObj.script = document.getElementById('scr').value;
        sObj.folder = document.getElementById('fldr').value;
        sObj.saveJson = document.getElementById('json').checked?'on':'';
        sObj.saveFiles = document.getElementById('files').checked?'on':'';
        sObj.selected = [];
        console.log("1");
        const cbs = document.getElementsByClassName("cbx");
        let selected = [];
        for(let i = 0;i<cbs.length; i++) {
          let cb = cbs[i];
          if(cb.checked) {
            sObj.selected.push(cb.value)
          } 
        }
        console.log("2");
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(obj){google.script.host.close();})
        .scriptFilesBackup(sObj);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(sObj));
      }
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

GS:

```
function saveScriptBackupsDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('backupscripts1'), 'Script Files Backup Dialog');
}

function scriptFilesBackup(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  const scriptId = obj.script.trim();
  const folderId = obj.folder.trim();
  const saveJson = obj.saveJson;
  const saveFiles = obj.saveFiles;
  const fA = obj.selected;
 
  if (scriptId && folderId) {
    const base = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/"
    const url1 = base + scriptId + "/content";
    const url2 = base + scriptId;
    const options = { "method": "get", "muteHttpExceptions": true, "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
    const res1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, options);
    const data1 = JSON.parse(res1.getContentText());
    const files = data1.files;
    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

    const res2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, options);
    const data2 = JSON.parse(res2.getContentText());
    let dts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss");
    let subFolderName = Utilities.formatString('%s-%s', data2.title, dts);
    let subFolder = folder.createFolder(subFolderName);
    if (saveFiles) {
      files.forEach(file => {
        if (file.source && file.name) {
          let ext = (file.type == "HTML") ? ".html" : ".gs";
          if (~fA.indexOf(file.name)) {
            subFolder.createFile(file.name + ext, file.source, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)
          }
        }
      });
    }
    if (saveJson) {
      subFolder.createFile(subFolderName + '_JSON', res1, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)
    }
  }
  return { "message": "Process Complete" };
}
```

And here's what the Dialog Looks like I use this code to save my functions in ascii files.

[image]